# Cannot import geopandas

Tags: python, error-handling, anaconda, geopandas

I have installed geopandas using Anaconda. However, when I try to import it, it always gives me this error:

```
could not find or load spatialindex_c-64.dll
```

Can someone explain what is causing this and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Try `pip uninstall rtree` and try again.

Comment: @Skully I uninstalled rtree and tried to import geopandas but it still did not work

Comment: can you  edit your question and tell us how exactly you installed geopandas and include the output of `conda list --show-channel-urls` as well?